# react-tooltip custom class is removing carat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, tooltip

I am using react-tooltip and passing in the optional data-class="nav-tooltip" to do custom styling on top of what comes out of the box. When I use the class in my sass file, the carat/pointer disappears. How can I use custom styling but keep the carat present? Has anyone come across this before?

This is my tooltip:

```
<div data-place="right" data-type="dark" data-effect="solid" data multiline="false" data-class="nav-tooltip" delayHide={1000} data-tip data-for='view'>
</div>

<ReactTooltip id='view' globalEventOff='click'>
  tooltip stuff
</ReactTooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default class that you're overriding with your own className is likely appending the carat using a pseudo-element like `:after`.  Try inspecting a tooltip without your custom class and add the default pseudo-element's styles to your custom class in your SASS.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I don't see css with the inspector that would be adding a carat. I see placement - margin and padding, etc